# How do you retrieve the first n lines of a file? (php)

Tags: php, file, fopen, tokenize, fputs

```
$fileName = file ("gstbook.txt");
$rows = count ($fileName);

// $Char is the string that will be added to the file.
if ($Char != '') 
{
  $Char = str_replace ("\n","<br>",$Char);
  $Char = strip_tags ($Char, '<br>');

  $newRow = '<tr><td>' . ($username) . ": " . ($Char) . '</td></tr>';

  $oldRows = join ('', file ('gstbook.txt') );
  $fileName = fopen ('gstbook.txt', 'w');
  fputs ($fileName, $oldRows . chr(13) . chr(10) . $newRow);
  fclose ($fileName);
}
```

i'm working from a tutorial on a website. it's a guestbook program that i'm trying to turn into a tiny chat for use with one of my other apps.

where i'm stuck has to do with these two lines:

```
  $oldRows = join ('', file ('gstbook.txt') );
```

and:

```
  fputs ($fileName, $oldRows . chr(13) . chr(10) . $newRow);
```

I can tell it's inputting the entire file into a single string. then outputting that string.
what i haven't been able to figure out from Google is how to make it input only the first *n* lines of a file into the $oldRows variable.

the good news is that the

```
</tr>
```

of each file line can act as a delimiter. The bad news is i don't know where to go from there.

Would anyone tell me how to limit the input of the $oldRows variable to just *n* lines from $filename OR on how to trim down the $oldRows variable to just *n* lines?

CORRECTION:

i need to get the **LAST** *n* lines of the file (newest is added to the end)

Comment: Did you try opening the file and reading N lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
array_map( 'trim', file( $filename ) );
```

this will return array of string, then you can use for/foreach

Comment: perfect. and with array_reverse i can make the last n lines the first n lines to count. Tks.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice)

Here's an example:

```
$data = file('file.txt');
$data = array_slice($data, count($data) - 1, null, true);
print_r($data);
```

In the above code the `count($data) - 1)` is where you set the *n* parameter, in this case it is fetching the last line of the file.